# Tramp problems with remote .bashrc

Tags: org-mode, tramp, ssh

I'm using org-mode and doing an ssh multihop into a remote server from our faculty.

```
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :dir "/ssh:user@remote|ssh:user@remote2:/home/user"
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC sh
ls -al
#+END_SRC
```

I notice that Tramp hangs forever and then quits with a "File not found" error when trying to read back results into the org-buffer. I also notice that the problem goes away when I remove my `.bashrc` file on the remote server.

I fear that the problem has to do with my `PS1` and `PS2` prompt settings on the remote, because they contain some escape sequences to change the prompt coloring - which I believe Tramp doesn't understand.

Is there a way to ask Tramp not to read my .bashrc?! Is that even possible?
Do you guys have any recommendation on the best way to approach my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add the following lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ $TERM = dumb ]]; then
    return
fi
```