# org-babel not sourcing remote .bashrc when using tramp

Tags: org-babel, tramp

When editing a remote file with tramp, I want org-babel source blocks to source the remote machine's .bashrc.

I found this workaround that does what I want:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :preamble ". ~/.bashrc"
echo $PATH
#+END_SRC
```

I can save a bit of typing by adding this to the top of the file, so it applies to all `bash` blocks in the file:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:HEADER-ARGS:bash: :prologue ". ~/.bashrc"
:END:
```

However, what I really want is for the combination of tramp + org-babel to treat a shell source block as if I've started bash interactively on the remote machine.

Is there a way to configure this as the default, or is my hacky solution the best/only way to achieve my goal?

I tried the following suggestions, with no noticeable effect:

- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62427/10036
- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31624/10036
- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46200/10036

[edit]

Based on one of the comments, I also tried adding this to my init file:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
             (list (regexp-quote "/sshx:ibp2-admin:")
                   "remote-shell" "/bin/bash"
                   "sh-extra-args" "-l -i"))
```

This makes the remote shell /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh, but did not source the ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: The first two links are identical.

Comment: Do `C-h i g(tramp)Remote shell setup hints`. It mentions that `tramp-shell-extra-args` are applied, so you might want to try adding `-i` to that.

Comment: @NickD thanks, I gave it a try and was able to change the remote shell, but adding `-i` or `-l` seems to have no effect.

Comment: D'oh  - the variable is called `tramp-sh-extra-args`. Still untested, so I don't know if it'll work or not (you may have tried it already if you read the doc, rather than going by my erroneous comment), but a variable that is used by somebody has a better chance of working !-)

Comment: You're right, the variable is `tramp-sh-extra-args`. According to the Tramp manual 4.14, setting a property using tramp-connection-properties prepends "tramp-" to the property name. To be thorough, I also tried using `tramp-sh-extra-args` instead, with no noticeable effect.